# Regexp to match "foo/bar" and not "foobar" wanted

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex that i can use in my tokenizer to compile a config file. Here is a snippet out of a class in php:

```
private $token = array(
    "PATH" => "([a-zA-Z\_-]+\.|\*\.)+([a-zA-Z\_-]+|\*)",
    "MIXED" => "[a-zA-Z0-9-_\(\)\/]{2,}",
    "STRING" => "[a-zA-Z-_]{2,}"
);

private function getToken($string) {
    foreach($this->token as $name => $pattern) {
        preg_match("/^".$pattern."/", $string, $match);
        if(!empty($match))
            return array($name, $match[0]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

"MIXED" should match "foo/bar" and not "foobar" and "STRING" should match "foobar" and not "foo/bar". Currently "foobar" and "foo/bar" are "MIXED".

How do i write this "AND NOT" in a single pattern down?

Thank you.

Comment: "MIXED" => "[a-zA-Z0-9-_\(\)]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_\(\)]+"

Comment: to be more precise: "MIXED" is also "foo()", "foo(255)"

Comment: Cougar is on the right path. What you want is to express the idea "contains at least one slash".

Comment: Which parsing strategy? First match? Largest match?

Comment: first match. A "CHARACTER" is at least.

Comment: @Kaz: yes, at least one slash or brackets or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will match any sequence of letters, digits, underscores, hyphens and slashes which contains at least one slash:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*
```

So this gives you a general idea how to reject tokens like `abc` while matching `ab/c`.  This is very similar to distinguishing floating-point constants from integer constants.

You should probably be tokenizing inputs like `foo/bar(255)` as four tokens: `foo/bar` `(` `255` and `)`.

Otherwise enforcing this slash requirement is complicated. The naive ways mean that `MIXED` can be something like these:

```
foo(255/255)
foo(/)
```

or even:

```
)/-
```

just because it contains a slash somewhere, not necessarily where you want.

Clarify your requirements.

Comment: Thank you! This did it for me:

`[a-zA-Z\"]*[\(\)\/\"][a-zA-Z0-9-_\(\)\'$%\"\.:\,\;\_\-\+\/<>#\?\s]*`

Now i can tokenize something like this:

    `field.type = smallint(5) unsigned`

into

   `PATH EQUAL MIXED`

Comment: `()` has no special meaning inside `[]`, no need to slash-escape it. Same for many of the others you slash escape in there, see http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt